# Confused about using realm.allObjects()

Tags: java, android, realm

I have just started using realm and i cant work out how to get all objects in the database.  I have looked at the documentation but I dont really understand it fully.  Here is what i have so far:

mainFragment.java

```
static List<Acronym> realmResults;
Realm realmDB;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acronyms_list, container, false);
    acronymList = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.acronymRecyclerView);
    addNewEntry = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    realmDB = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());

    adapter = new acronymListAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    acronymList.setAdapter(adapter);
    acronymList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    realmDB.beginTransaction();

    realmResults = realmDB.allObjects(RealmAcronym.class);

    realmDB.commitTransaction();

}
```

RealmAcronym.java

```
public class RealmAcronym extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String          acronym;
private String          acronymFull;
private String          color;

@Ignore
private int             sessionId;

// Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
public String getAcronym() { return acronym; }
public void   setAcronym(String acronym) { this.acronym = acronym; }
public String getAcronymFull() { return acronymFull; }
public void   setAcronymFull(String acronymFull) { this.acronymFull = acronymFull; }
public String getColor() { return color; }
public void   setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }
public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
public void   setSessionId(int dontPersist) { this.sessionId = sessionId; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Your result should end up in a `RealmResults<RealmAcronym>` class rather than a `List` (to avoid having to copy out all the objects).
2. Transactions are only needed when you change data, not to just read it.

   ```
   static RealmResults<RealmAcronym> realmResults;
   Realm realmDB;

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       realmResults = realmDB.allObjects(RealmAcronym.class);
   }
   ```